# LWC Extend Omniscript Elements

Tags: lightning-web-components, vlocity, omnistudio

I am trying to understand how to work with the Omniscript elements and extend their functionality. There is very limited info from Salesforce.

Anyone worked with these requirements before?

Answer (score 1):

There's [developer docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/files/credential-resources/OmniStudio-Documentation.pdf) that cover exactly this. From pg. 810 (Extend Vlocity Lightning Web Components)

> To make the custom Lightning web component compatible with OmniStudio Vlocity Lightning web
> components, you must set two metadata tags in your XML configuration file:
>
> - Add the namespace of your OmniStudio Vlocity package using the runtimeNamespace metadata
>   tag. See the code example on this page. For more information on finding the namespace of your
>   package, see Viewing the Namespace and Version of the OmniStudio Vlocity Package.

The doc provides the following example of a custom LWC that extends the Button Lightning Web Component

```js
import Button from "NS/button";
export default class buttonExtended extends Button {
    //override the property here so it gets triggered
    onclickbutton() {
       this.label = "Button clicked";
    }
}
```

*XML configuration file*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://
soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>button_extended</masterLabel>
    <description>Button extended</description>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
    <runtimeNamespace>NS</runtimeNamespace>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

```html
<template>
//add HTML here to override the template layout
</template>
```

```css
//add CSS to override or append the SLDS theme css
.slds-button {
    background: #cccccc;
    border-color: #dddddd;
}
```

---

However, there's many more examples in the doc that cover interacting with OmniScript:

- Extend an OmniScript Element's Lightning Web Component (pg. 154)
- Extend the OmniScriptBaseMixin Component (pg. 156)
- Communicate with OmniScript from a Lightning Web Component (pg. 171)
- Make Remote Calls from Lightning Web Components using the OmniScript Action Framework (pg. 174)
- Extend and Override an OmniScript Modal Lightning Web Component (pg. 182)

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/380354/invalid-element-error-for-runtimenamespace
Not able to save meta file . It is giving error invalid element error for <runtimeNamespace>

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources I've found regarding extending OmniScript component functionality:

- new Salesforce Trail: [OmniStudio and Custom LWCs](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/omnistudio-and-custom-lightning-web-components)
- this video (and others on this YouTube Channel): [Extend Element's Based LWC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uT-W44mmaGM&t=1192s)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.