# invalid element error for <runtimeNamespace>

Tags: lightning-web-components, visualstudiocode

I am getting an error in xml file while building LWC (want to use with vlocity component) in VS Code.

Please help me to resolve this error.

Here is the xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <runtimeNamespace>vlocity_cmt</runtimeNamespace>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <runtimeNamespace>vlocity_cmt</runtimeNamespace>
</LightningComponentBundle>

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please do not post additional information that is for the question as a comment. Instead, edit your original question to add the additional information. At the bottom left of every post (question and answer) you see "Share Edit Follow Flag". Click *Edit* under your question to edit it to add the information.

Comment: Is this issue resolved I am also facing same issue

Comment: Issue is not resolved. But I ignored the error and saved the file and I could deploy. it is working. but not sure about the error.